# apply one function to a tensor with depth

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensor

I wrote a function using tensorflow like y = f(x) and it works well with one image like (1, 4, 4, 1). Now I do not know how to apply that to an image or tensor like x = (1, 4, 4, 32). If it was a python or C++ I could use a for loop with 32 iterations and apply my function on each slice and merge them into one image in output like y = (1, 4, 4, 32). 
For better explanation, imagine

```
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
```

how it work on filters? Is it apply one time for each filter or not? Is there any function in tensorflow that apply one operator on each depth and concatanate them?
I was thinking to use while_loop but its difficult in tensorflow. If its the only way, could somebody let me know how to work with while loop with a simple example using x, f, and y?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No body will answer this??

Comment: Can you give more detail about the function you wrote? One simple solution would be trying to apply the TimeDistributed wrapper to your function before using it.

Comment: Its a simple function of max pooling with indices. As an example, consider a simple function that apply a filter for each channel of an image with many channels. I asked similar question here:(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146613/loop-in-tensorflow)